# Can you play Magic The Gathering: Tactics offline?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-tactics

I've seen it's got a single player campaign and the SE Downloader has an option that says "Game mode: Live" or something like that. Is it possible to play this game with no connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of MTGT you have to have an internet connection to log in, and you must maintain this connection or you will be kicked off.